# How do you remove inline styles in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am currently trying to remove inline styles that come from the wysiwyg in Wordpress. My problem comes from editors styling their blog posts and its looking terrible, the main culprit being font sizes.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin for Wordpress? OR if anyone knows if it is possible to turn off CSS inline styles in tinyMCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1522 might be what you are looking for. It's also possible in tinymce to have different levels of editor (minimal, regular, +kitchen sink).  Perhaps using one of those may serve your purpose better.